# If $|x^2-x-5|+(3x+6)=0$, then how many values of $x$ exist?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

If $|x^2-x-5|+(3x+6)=0$, then how many values of $x$ exist?

What I did: when $x^2-x-5\geq0$
$x^2-x-5=-(3x+6)$
On solving I got $x=-1$. Then I took intersection of $x=-1$ and domain that is zero. On intersection there was no such value of $x$.

When $x^2-x-5<0$, on solving I got my answer in root. Now, I don't know what to do next and I don't know if I am doing it in a right way.

Please guys let me know if my way of solving it is right.

Comment: Is the absolute value (mod) on $x^2-x+5$ only? I.e. $|x^2-x+5|+3x+6=0$?You need to edit the question, use vertical bars for the absolute values.

Comment: done! @AnuragA Now, please see

Answer (score 0):

Observe that when we have $|a|=b$, then $b \geq 0$. You are given

$$|x^2-x-5|=-(3x+6).$$

So here if there is a solution then it can only occur when $3x+6 \leq 0$, same as saying $x \leq -2$.

Now for your second case, when $x^2-x-5 < 0$, the quadratic you get is $x^2-4x-11=0$, it has two roots $x=2 \pm \sqrt{15}$. None of the roots satisfy the condition $x \leq -2$, hence NO solution.

Graphically things are as shown below.

[image]

Comment: What I have done is wrong?@AnuragA

Comment: @ShobhitGupta no your approach is right I have just completed your approach and made an observation about where the solutions can possibly lie. In most absolute value problems you do consider two cases (just like you did).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

What you have done is correct. Your equation is equivalent to the two systems:
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2-x-5\ge0\\
x^2-x-5+3x+6=0
\end{cases}
\quad \lor \quad
\begin{cases}
x^2-x-5<0\\
-x^2+x+5+3x+6=0
\end{cases}
$$
and you have correctly found that the first system has no solutions.

Now, the equation in the second  system has some  solution ($ x=2\pm\sqrt{15}$) in the interval that solve the inequality $(\frac{1-\sqrt{21}}{2},\frac{1+\sqrt{21}}{2})$?  Can you evaluate this? (you can use approximation of the roots).

Comment: The roots for the second equation are $\color{red}{+}2\pm \sqrt{15}$.

Comment: Also the interval you get from the first inequality is sort of irrelevant as the solution can only exist when $ x \leq -2$.

Comment: Thank you @AnuragA: fixed.

Comment: @EmilioNovati firstly I calculated the domain $x^2-x-5\geq0$ it gave me $1+\sqrt(21)/2$. and $1-\sqrt(21)/2$. Which is approximately equal to -2 and 2.5. Taking intersection of domain with -1 gives me the answer  (-1,-2). First system is giving me solution. Tried it again

Comment: @AnuragA please see my comment above

Comment: @ShobhitGupta I have given you a proof as well as graphical evidence of non-existence of the solution. Now regarding your comment: the mistake you are making is when $(x-a)(x-b) \geq 0$, then assuming $a>b$, the solution for this inequality is $x \leq b$ or $x \geq a$, said differently anything that *DOES NOT LIE* in the interval $(a,b)$ is a solution. So in your case the solution for $x^2-x-5 \geq 0$ is all numbers that *DO NOT LIE* in the interval $\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{21}}{2}, \frac{1+\sqrt{21}}{2}\right)$. Clearly $x=-1$ lies in this interval so it *CANNOT* be a solution.